# Replace a color with another color in an image with PHP

Tags: php, imagick

Yes I know there are related questions available on stackoverflow but they are not perfectly work as per my need. I am trying to replace a color of an image with another color. In below code I am replacing (255,0,255) with (0,192,239).
**Below code works but not perfectly replacing new color over pink(255,0,255) color some minor dots or border of pink color is still remaining as you can see in output image.**

> **How can i get its perfect solution ?**

```
<?php
$filename = 'img/Mascots_Aviators_General-copy.png'; 
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 254, 254, 254, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $transColor);

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);

        $red = ($pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $alpha = ($pixel & 0x7F000000) >> 24;

        if ($red == 255 && $green == 0 && $blue == 255) {
            $red = 0;
            $green=192;
            $blue =239;
        }

        if ($alpha == 127) {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $transColor);
        }
        else {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha));
        }
    }
} 
imagecolortransparent($out, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($out, TRUE); 
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
```

[image: Original image]
[image: output image]

Comment: That's because those lines are not `(255,0,255) ` exactly. You need to implement color range for this to work.

Comment: @Helix Yeah i have tried this by keeping range ($red <= 255 && $red >= 245) && ($green >= 0 && $green <= 10) && ($blue <= 255 && $blue >= 245)  but output is still as same. Is i am correct ?

Comment: Give me a second and I'll try to post an answer. Having trouble with basic math.

Comment: So, did the new solution work?

Comment: @Helix Might be Yes but not completely Sure I am including this code in my library and will run it for other images too once it's done I will reply you

Comment: @Helix Is it possible to chat with you ?
I have a problem when I include this code in my main lib.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90308/discussion-between-anand-jain-and-helix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2 :**
You might need to optimize something and change `hueAbsoluteError` to suit your needs, but hue is the way to enlightenment and sharper picture quality (functions taken from https://gist.github.com/brandonheyer/5254516):

```
<?php
function RGBtoHSL( $r, $g, $b ) {
    $r /= 255;
    $g /= 255;
    $b /= 255;
    $max = max( $r, $g, $b );
    $min = min( $r, $g, $b );
    $l = ( $max + $min ) / 2;
    $d = $max - $min;
    if( $d == 0 ){
        $h = $s = 0;
    } else {
        $s = $d / ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) );
        switch( $max ){
            case $r:
                $h = 60 * fmod( ( ( $g - $b ) / $d ), 6 );
                if ($b > $g) {
                    $h += 360;
                }
                break;
            case $g:
                $h = 60 * ( ( $b - $r ) / $d + 2 );
                break;
            case $b:
                $h = 60 * ( ( $r - $g ) / $d + 4 );
                break;
        }
    }
    return array( round( $h, 2 ), round( $s, 2 ), round( $l, 2 ) );
}

function HSLtoRGB( $h, $s, $l ){
    $c = ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) ) * $s;
    $x = $c * ( 1 - abs( fmod( ( $h / 60 ), 2 ) - 1 ) );
    $m = $l - ( $c / 2 );
    if ( $h < 60 ) {
        $r = $c;
        $g = $x;
        $b = 0;
    } else if ( $h < 120 ) {
        $r = $x;
        $g = $c;
        $b = 0;
    } else if ( $h < 180 ) {
        $r = 0;
        $g = $c;
        $b = $x;
    } else if ( $h < 240 ) {
        $r = 0;
        $g = $x;
        $b = $c;
    } else if ( $h < 300 ) {
        $r = $x;
        $g = 0;
        $b = $c;
    } else {
        $r = $c;
        $g = 0;
        $b = $x;
    }
    $r = ( $r + $m ) * 255;
    $g = ( $g + $m ) * 255;
    $b = ( $b + $m  ) * 255;
    return array( floor( $r ), floor( $g ), floor( $b ) );
}

/* ---------------CHANGE THESE------------------- */
$colorToReplace = RGBtoHSL(255, 0, 255);
$hueAbsoluteError = 0.4;
$replacementColor = RGBtoHSL(0, 192, 239);
/* ---------------------------------------------- */

$filename = 'img/Mascots_Aviators_General-copy.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 254, 254, 254, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $transColor);

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);

        $red = ($pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $alpha = ($pixel & 0x7F000000) >> 24;

        $colorHSL = RGBtoHSL($red, $green, $blue);

        if ((($colorHSL[0]  >= $colorToReplace[0] - $hueAbsoluteError) && ($colorToReplace[0] + $hueAbsoluteError) >= $colorHSL[0])){
            $color = HSLtoRGB($replacementColor[0], $replacementColor[1], $colorHSL[2]);
            $red = $color[0];
            $green= $color[1];
            $blue = $color[2];
        }

        if ($alpha == 127) {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $transColor);
        }
        else {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha));
        }
    }
}
imagecolortransparent($out, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($out, TRUE);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
```

[image]

**EDIT :**
Better solution - determine if color needs replacement (using this method). Determine replaced color's hue (I have no idea if it's correct term, what I mean is lightness and darkness). Apply it to replacement color to give it a shade or AA feeling.

---

So, as I have said in my comment, you need to determine if this color is really ping (dark, light, etc.). Easiest solution is to apply absolute error method for specific color channels. There may be (there definitely is) better universal method, but I hope this will do:

```
$color = [255, 0, 255];
$colorAbsoluteError = [150, 0, 150];
$replacementColor = [0, 192, 239];
$filename = 'img/Mascots_Aviators_General-copy.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 254, 254, 254, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $transColor);

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);

        $red = ($pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $alpha = ($pixel & 0x7F000000) >> 24;

        if ((($red  >= $color[0] - $colorAbsoluteError[0]) && ($color[0] + $colorAbsoluteError[0]) >= $red) &&
            (($green  >= $color[1] - $colorAbsoluteError[1]) && ($color[1] + $colorAbsoluteError[1]) >= $green) &&
            (($blue  >= $color[2] - $colorAbsoluteError[2]) && ($color[2] + $colorAbsoluteError[2]) >= $blue)){
            $red = $replacementColor[0];
            $green= $replacementColor[1];
            $blue = $replacementColor[2];
        }

        if ($alpha == 127) {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $transColor);
        }
        else {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha));
        }
    }
}
imagecolortransparent($out, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($out, TRUE);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
```

[image]

Comment: I have run above code first, it looses output image quality second when I change file(image) it take blue background and completely destroyed the output image.

Comment: I'll try another solution with HSL colorspace.