# Replace the specific RGB color with another image using PHP

Tags: php, image, replace, colors, background

I derived a perfect color replace script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710756/1620626. I want to replace the target color with the image background. The original image is backgrounded with light green `(rgb:0b255b1)`. I can replace it with blue but I don't have an idea how to replace with the image. Here's the script.

This is the original image.
[image: 01.jpg]

Once I process this photo with the script. I've got this.
[image]

The script is perfectly replace the target color with the new one. Now I want to change from blue into the background. So the final idea is. This girl on the background image I chosen.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710756/1620626
function RGBtoHSL( $r, $g, $b ) {
    $r /= 255;
    $g /= 255;
    $b /= 255;
    $max = max( $r, $g, $b );
    $min = min( $r, $g, $b );
    $l = ( $max + $min ) / 2;
    $d = $max - $min;
    if( $d == 0 ){
        $h = $s = 0;
    } else {
        $s = $d / ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) );
        switch( $max ){
            case $r:
                $h = 60 * fmod( ( ( $g - $b ) / $d ), 6 );
                if ($b > $g) {
                    $h += 360;
                }
                break;
            case $g:
                $h = 60 * ( ( $b - $r ) / $d + 2 );
                break;
            case $b:
                $h = 60 * ( ( $r - $g ) / $d + 4 );
                break;
        }
    }
    return array( round( $h, 2 ), round( $s, 2 ), round( $l, 2 ) );
}

function HSLtoRGB( $h, $s, $l ){
    $c = ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) ) * $s;
    $x = $c * ( 1 - abs( fmod( ( $h / 60 ), 2 ) - 1 ) );
    $m = $l - ( $c / 2 );
    if ( $h < 60 ) {
        $r = $c;
        $g = $x;
        $b = 0;
    } else if ( $h < 120 ) {
        $r = $x;
        $g = $c;
        $b = 0;
    } else if ( $h < 180 ) {
        $r = 0;
        $g = $c;
        $b = $x;
    } else if ( $h < 240 ) {
        $r = 0;
        $g = $x;
        $b = $c;
    } else if ( $h < 300 ) {
        $r = $x;
        $g = 0;
        $b = $c;
    } else {
        $r = $c;
        $g = 0;
        $b = $x;
    }
    $r = ( $r + $m ) * 255;
    $g = ( $g + $m ) * 255;
    $b = ( $b + $m  ) * 255;
    return array( floor( $r ), floor( $g ), floor( $b ) );
}

/* ---------------CHANGE THESE------------------- */
$colorToReplace = RGBtoHSL(0,255,1);//target color
$hueAbsoluteError = 7;//the more the clearer
$replacementColor = RGBtoHSL(0, 192, 239);//new color
/* ---------------------------------------------- */

$filename = 'images/01.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 254, 254, 254, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $transColor);

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);

        $red = ($pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $alpha = ($pixel & 0x7F000000) >> 24;

        $colorHSL = RGBtoHSL($red, $green, $blue);

        if ((($colorHSL[0]  >= $colorToReplace[0] - $hueAbsoluteError) && ($colorToReplace[0] + $hueAbsoluteError) >= $colorHSL[0])){
            $color = HSLtoRGB($replacementColor[0], $replacementColor[1], $colorHSL[2]);
            $red = $color[0];
            $green= $color[1];
            $blue = $color[2];
        }

        if ($alpha == 127) {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $transColor);
        }
        else {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha));
        }
    }
}
imagecolortransparent($out, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($out, TRUE);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just read two images, source and background, and take pixels from background image and set to the source.

Below is the last part of your code above which shows this idea:

```
$filename = 'images/01.png';
$bgFilename = 'images/background.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$bg = imagecreatefrompng($bgFilename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 254, 254, 254, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $transColor);

for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
        $bgPixel = imagecolorat($bg, $x, $y);

        $red = ($pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $green = ($pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $blue = $pixel & 0xFF;
        $alpha = ($pixel & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
        $colorHSL = RGBtoHSL($red, $green, $blue);

        if ((($colorHSL[0]  >= $colorToReplace[0] - $hueAbsoluteError) && ($colorToReplace[0] + $hueAbsoluteError) >= $colorHSL[0])){
            // Instead of taking the replacementColor
            /* $color = HSLtoRGB($replacementColor[0], $replacementColor[1], $colorHSL[2]); */
            /* $red = $color[0]; */
            /* $green= $color[1]; */
            /* $blue = $color[2]; */
            // We just take colors from the backround image pixel
            $red = ($bgPixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $green = ($bgPixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $blue = $bgPixel & 0xFF;
        }

        if ($alpha == 127) {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $transColor);
        }
        else {
            imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($out, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha));
        }
    }
}
imagecolortransparent($out, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($out, TRUE);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
```

The result can look like this:

[image]

Comment: The result is looking great, but I got Error 500 on my server. What's wrong? http://phuket.my/irp/

Comment: @Wilf you need to check logs or debug it in some other way, from 500 error is is not possible to say what is the problem. [Here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/php-image-background) is the full code I used, download the whole folder or clone the repository, run as `php convert.php > out.png`, source images are under `images/`.