# Replace Image color to transparent with imagegd php

Tags: php, image, colors, gd, transparent

I found this link [Replace a color with another color in an image with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32710180/4247225) and it works
but I want to replace color with transparent, how can I do that?

May someone want to help me to solve this problem

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i know, just add some line after forloop here's full sourcecode

```
`https://pastebin.com/S6YVhTha
```

i hope this help someone who need this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my script
if you have installed Imagick Library in your server

https://github.com/1fer/wp_image_color_replace/blob/master/includes/replacecolor

./replacecolor -i "{what color shold be replaced}" -o "{to what color}" -f 40 -g 50 {path to img} {path to new image}

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.